# How to make radio group buttons display horizontally instead of vertically?

Tags: google-app-maker, radio-group

I have created a dynamic table in Google App Maker to display class attendance information.  Each row contains information for one student and there are multiple rows for the entire class.  I would like to use a radio group so the teacher can select a one of several attendance options (i.e., Present, Tardy, Excused, Unexcused).  However, the radio group buttons are displayed vertically within each row and take up a lot of space.  Is there any way in Google App Maker to change the orientation of the radio group to display horizontally?

I have checked the Google App Maker Widget API which describes properties for the radio group and there is some discussion about in-flow widgets and how they behave with different layout widgets.  I am using a vertical panel for the table.  However, the radio group behaves the same for horizontal and fixed panels.  Other app programs (like for Android) include properties for orientation, however, I see no such property in Google App Maker.

I prefer to use a radio group since the options are mutually exclusive.  If I can't change the radio group orientation, I could use individual check boxes but I would need to add the code so the options are automatically treated as mutually exclusive.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Towards the top next to your 'Widgets' menu, there is a dropdown to select a style variant. 'Horizontal' is an option under this category for a radio group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you, Markus!  I'm including a picture and repeating your answer to highlight it for others.

Towards the top next to your 'Widgets' menu, there is a dropdown menu to select style variants.  Horizontal is listed as an option under this category for a radio group.  For other objects, this menu usually lists the background color or text style.

[image: Screenshot of dropdown menu to choose orientation for radio group]

Comment: Hi, do you know how to have multi select shown in horizontal too? it doesn't have a horizontal layout. Thanks.